# Spell Checking Service with python using mod_python

Tags: spell-checking, mod-python, aspell

What is the best available method for developing a spell check engine (for example, with `aspell_python`), that works with apache `mod_python`?

`apache 2.0.59+RHEL4+mod_python+aspell_python` seems to crash.

Is there any alternative to using `aspell_python`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like RHEL4 is the culprit. Works well on Fedore 7 (the version of apache is newer and there is no crash)